not able to retrieve solflare wallet address
My code is running on local in py eni , I am trying to get solflare wallet address after connecting to it but it getting error
here is the full code
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="{{ url_for('static', filename='styles.css') }}">
    <title>Connect Solana Wallet</title>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="container">
        <h1>Connect Your Solana Wallet</h1>
        <button id="connect-phantom">Connect Phantom</button>
        <button id="connect-solflare">Connect Solflare</button>
        <button id="connect-backpack">Connect Backpack</button>
        <p id="wallet-address"></p>
        <div id="result"></div>
    </div>

    <script>
        async function connectWallet(wallet) {
            let response;
            try {
                if (wallet === 'Phantom') {
                    const { solana } = window;
                    if (solana && solana.isPhantom) {
                        response = await solana.connect();
                    } else {
                        alert('Please install Phantom Wallet!');
                        return;
                    }
                } else if (wallet === 'Solflare') {
                    if (window.solflare) {
                        response = await window.solflare.connect();
                        // Solflare might require fetching the publicKey separately
                        if (!response.publicKey && window.solflare.publicKey) {
                            response.publicKey = window.solflare.publicKey;
                        }
                    } else {
                        alert('Please install Solflare Wallet!');
                        return;
                    }
                } else if (wallet === 'Backpack') {
                    if (window.backpack) {
                        response = await window.backpack.connect();
                    } else {
                        alert('Please install Backpack Wallet!');
                        return;
                    }
                }

                if (response && response.publicKey) {
                    document.getElementById('wallet-address').innerText = `Wallet Address: ${response.publicKey.toString()}`;
                    getURLParams(response.publicKey.toString());
                } else {
                    alert('Unable to retrieve wallet address.');
                }
            } catch (error) {
                console.error('Error connecting wallet:', error);
                alert('Failed to connect to the wallet.');
            }
        }

        document.getElementById('connect-phantom').onclick = () => connectWallet('Phantom');
        document.getElementById('connect-solflare').onclick = () => connectWallet('Solflare');
        document.getElementById('connect-backpack').onclick = () => connectWallet('Backpack');

        async function getURLParams(walletAddress) {
            const params = new URLSearchParams(window.location.search);
            const merkleTreeRoot = params.get('Merkle_Tree_Root');

            try {
                const response = await fetch(`/check_merkle_tree/${walletAddress}/${merkleTreeRoot}`);
                const result = await response.json();
                document.getElementById('result').innerText = result.message;
            } catch (error) {
                console.error('Error fetching merkle tree:', error);
                document.getElementById('result').innerText = 'Error fetching merkle tree details.';
            }
        }
    </script>
</body>
</html>


await window.solflare.connect()

The method above returns a boolean on whether connecting the wallet was successful,
change the lines connecting solflare wallet to this
  let isConnected = await window.solflare.connect();
  if (isConnected) response = window.solflare;

full snippet
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="{{ url_for('static', filename='styles.css') }}">
    <title>Connect Solana Wallet</title>
</head>

<body>
    <div class="container">
        <h1>Connect Your Solana Wallet</h1>
        <button id="connect-phantom">Connect Phantom</button>
        <button id="connect-solflare">Connect Solflare</button>
        <button id="connect-backpack">Connect Backpack</button>
        <p id="wallet-address"></p>
        <div id="result"></div>
    </div>

    <script>
        async function connectWallet(wallet) {
            let response;
            try {
                if (wallet === 'Phantom') {
                    const { solana } = window;
                    if (solana?.isPhantom) {
                        response = await solana.connect();
                    } else {
                        alert('Please install Phantom Wallet!');
                        return;
                    }
                } else if (wallet === 'Solflare') {
                    if (window.solflare) {
                        let isConnected = await window.solflare.connect();
                        if (isConnected) response = window.solflare;
                    } else {
                        alert('Please install Solflare Wallet!');
                        return;
                    }
                } else if (wallet === 'Backpack') {
                    if (window.backpack) {
                        response = await window.backpack.connect();
                    } else {
                        alert('Please install Backpack Wallet!');
                        return;
                    }
                }

                if (response?.publicKey) {
                    document.getElementById('wallet-address').innerText = `Wallet Address: ${response.publicKey.toString()}`;
                    getURLParams(response.publicKey.toString());
                } else {
                    alert('Unable to retrieve wallet address.');
                }
            } catch (error) {
                console.error('Error connecting wallet:', error);
                alert('Failed to connect to the wallet.');
            }
        }

        document.getElementById('connect-phantom').onclick = () => connectWallet('Phantom');
        document.getElementById('connect-solflare').onclick = () => connectWallet('Solflare');
        document.getElementById('connect-backpack').onclick = () => connectWallet('Backpack');

        async function getURLParams(walletAddress) {
            const params = new URLSearchParams(window.location.search);
            const merkleTreeRoot = params.get('Merkle_Tree_Root');

            try {
                const response = await fetch(`/check_merkle_tree/${walletAddress}/${merkleTreeRoot}`);
                const result = await response.json();
                document.getElementById('result').innerText = result.message;
            } catch (error) {
                console.error('Error fetching merkle tree:', error);
                document.getElementById('result').innerText = 'Error fetching merkle tree details.';
            }
        }
    </script>
</body>

</html>


thank you so much
